# Missing } inserted. \end{align} fail to create equation

Tags: equations, align

When I try to compile my LaTeX file, where begin{align} environment is to be used, I get an error:

my command is :

```
\begin{align}
    \textbf{Y}_{it}  = \alpha + {\sum}_l{\beta}_l\{t-\text{E}_i=l\}*treatment_i + $X$_{it}\Gamma + \phi_i + \gamma_t + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{align}
```

[image]

the output is kind of funny
[image]

since it gives me"programepstopdf" in pdf view....

also try in begin{equation} and end{equation}, still throws error.
Does someone know what did i do wrong here? also checked other questions and answers but not solve it.

Comment: Use `\mathbf`, not `\textbf` in the context of math formulas. And `\mathrm`, not `\text` for a letter you want upright. Also `treatment` should be `\mathit{treatment}`.

Comment: There's also no reason for encasing `\sum` and `\beta` in curly braces. In fact, encasing `\sum` in curly braces is a rather bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly used `$` in `align` which is also math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \textbf{Y}_{it}  = \alpha + {\sum}_l{\beta}_l\{t-\text{E}_i=l\}*treatment_i + X_{it}\Gamma + \phi_i + \gamma_t + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Please don't encase `\sum` in curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `$X$`, because `$` initiates or ends math mode, but the contents of `align` is already in math mode.

There's much room for improvements, though.

1. Avoid `align` for a single equation, it's for aligning multiple ones (or parts thereof)
2. `\textbf{Y}` should be `\mathbf{Y}`
3. `\text{E}` should be `\mathrm{E}`, assuming you want the letter to be upright
4. The letters `treatment` are considered a product of several variables; if you want to mean a single multiletter variable, use `\mathit{treatment}`
5. `*` is never used in mathematics for denoting multiplication
6. I guess you don't want `\sum`, but `\Sigma`
7. Avoid redundant braces

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y}_{it}  = 
\alpha + \Sigma_l\beta_l\{t-\mathrm{E}_i=l\}\cdot \mathit{treatment}_i 
+ X_{it}\Gamma + \phi_i + \gamma_t + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, maybe, you want `\sum`, but with the subscript on the side. In this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y}_{it}  = 
\alpha + \sum\nolimits_l\beta_l\{t-\mathrm{E}_i=l\}\cdot \mathit{treatment}_i 
+ X_{it}\Gamma + \phi_i + \gamma_t + \varepsilon_{it}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. "I guess you don't want `\sum`, but `\Sigma`". Actually, my guess is that what the OP wants is `\sum\nolimits_l`...

Comment: @Mico Agreed and added.